# How to provide a label / name over a place with Google Maps Embed API?

Tags: google-maps

How to provide a label / name over a place with Google Maps Embed API with coordinates in URL query string ?

I use the below code in the HTML page :

```
<iframe width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&key=map_api_key"></iframe>
```

It displays the Google Map with a red balloon but displays no label / text next to the balloon. 
How to display a label / text for the place pointed by the red balloon ?

**UPDATE**
Looks like a Feature Enhancement Request was submitted to Google long back but still it has not gathered enough support to get implemented.

I have starred it. Please star it if you need it too.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1612

Comment: You probably need to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 for that functionality.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks. I wanted something in Embed API. I had hoped that there would be a query string parameter to set it.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do that using [**marker & infowindow**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) using the Google Maps Javascript API v3. I attached the detailed example with sample code. It's a good start. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted something in Embed API. I had hoped that there would be a query string parameter to set it.